# Protective APIs in Microsoft Teams returns 403 even after Protected APIs are enabled

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We raised request to enable Protected APIs for our apps and for all tenant and got mail stats that Protected APIs are enabled .

We try out we got the Application access token as mentioned in [MSTeams Application OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) through POSTMAN.

We enabled Group.ReadWrite.All and ChannelMessage.Read.All and performed Admin consent.

When tried on List channel message API(GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/messages)) using application permission through POSTMAN we got 403 error as below

`{ "error": { "code": "UnknownError", "message": "", "innerError": { "date": "2020-06-30T12:40:36", "request-id": "7b840d44-96e7-4edc-b083-9ecb904ba161" } } }`

Since the Protected APIs are already enabled as per the mail 403-Forbidden shouldn't occur.

Is that anything missed out ?

Comment: Could you please check you have the permissions listed out in access_token? you can check it over [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)

Comment: Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT . In the Application OAuth URL (https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token) if we put 'common' for <TenantId> then no Roles are shown in JWT parse.

  If Tenant Id of the app is put in <TenantId> then configured roles are shown and list channel messages query is working good.

Our app works for multi-tenant . So are we need to perform application authentication for each tenant and get access token for each tenant ? Or just we can use the tenant Id of App to perform application auth and use the access token for all tenants ?

Comment: Better to use <tenant-id > to get access token, you can fetch the tenant id from bot Activity itself

Comment: <tenant-id> for each and every tenant. Right ?

Comment: Yes you can replace the tenant-id after reading it from activity

Comment: can you show what reply you got for your request for these APIs?